# Free JavaScript Charting Library

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, javascript, charts

Please suggest some free JavaScript charting library. I need it for basic usage for gauge and line chart creation.

(Highchart and Canvas.js are not free for commercial use).

I need to create a gauge for something like [this Highchart  example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer).

Answer (score 1):

imo [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) is one of the best free Chart.js charting library for JS. If you don't like that there is [C3js](https://c3js.org/) and [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/javascript/)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As you see, all well-received answers here are [more than just a link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232). Please consider [edit]ing your answer and add more information about the software, especially how it meets the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1.elycharts 
 2.D3.js 
 3.google charts!
 4.C3.js

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As you see, all well-received answers here are [more than just a link or a name of the product](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232). Please consider [edit]ing your answer and add more information about the software, especially how it meets the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Syncfusion JS libraries. It has very good charts, gauges, maps, and more than 60+ other controls as well, and the best part is you can get it for free if you are an individual developer or if your company is generating less than 1 million in revenue. If you are eligible you can get the community license and try it out.

Chart demos: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/chart/line

Feature Tour: https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-charts

Note: I work for Syncfusion.